# How to set shape.Position without creating new Point objects in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, graphics

I have 1000s shapes whose `StartPoint`, `EndPoint`, `Center`, etc is being set 30 times per second but the only way to do this is to create a new `Point` each time, since `System.Windows.Point` is a struct so I can't do this:

```
shape.Center.X = x;
```

And there is not even a `SetCenter`, etc method to solve this.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Have you profiled your application to make sure creating those structures is your bottleneck (or at least a bottleneck both worth investigating and attempting to optimize)? I heavily suspect you haven't and is assuming creating Point structures is a costly operation. Profile first!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you want to create new Points?

They're simple value types, no memory or performance issues that I can see.

Comment: +1 ....90,000 Point structs per second on a computer that runs at more than 1 GHz. Bah! The code that renders the objects will easily swamp the setting of the points.

Comment: +1, I can't conceive that this has any noticeable impact at all on performance.  Try profiling.

Comment: True but I want to make this as fast as possible because then I could increase the number of iterations per second and also the number of shapes.

Comment: It's impossible to guess at performance problems.  I am 99% sure what you're talking about above cannot possibly be your problem.  Run a WPF specific profiler.  Microsoft describes techniques here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Joan, if you "want to make this as fast as possible" then use a profiler to find the real problems. This isn't the bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Use TranslateTransform to place the shapes. Use the RenderTransformOrigin to set the 'center'.

**EDIT**

RenderTransforms can be accelerated by the GPU. 
You wouldn't add a transformation each frame but add just one and change its properties over time. See [BitmapCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapcache%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [this is also quite interesting](http://jeremiahmorrill.com/2011/02/14/a-critical-deep-dive-into-the-wpf-rendering-system/)

Comment: Thanks but are the method calls? It seems like they are also objects? I need to do this separately for each shape.

Comment: Probably a good idea although adding Transforms isn't likely to be faster.

Comment: I added to my answer to explain more.